# Вывод позиции в списке, а не значения

Tags: python

Есть код:

```py
lst = [int(i) for i in input().split()]

x = int(input())

position = [number for number in lst if number == x]

if not position:
    print('Отсуствует')
else:
    print(*position)
```

При выводе нужно получить все позиции, на которых встречается число `x` в переданном списке `lst`, а не `х`. Не могу понять как это сделать.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для прохода по коллекции с нумерацией элементов используется функция [`enumerate`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate):

```
lst = [2, 3, 4, 1, 1, 3]
x = 3
position = [i for i, number in enumerate(lst) if number == x]
print(position)  # [1, 5]
```

Что делает `enumerate`:

```
print(list(enumerate([2, 3, 4, 1, 1, 3])))
```

выводит

```
[(0, 2), (1, 3), (2, 4), (3, 1), (4, 1), (5, 3)]
```

т.е. для каждого элемента исходной последовательности возвращается индекс элемента и сам элемент.

Answer (score 0):

Если вам нужно написать код самостоятельно, то нужно всего лишь перебирать индексы вместо элементов списка:

```
position = [number for number in range(len(lst)) if lst[number] == x]
```

И, кстати, есть такая функция index():
list.index(element) - дает индекс первого появления элемента в списке